# SPARQL: How to list all possibilities that does not contradicts a universal restriction

Tags: sparql, restriction, universal

Is it possible to construct a SPARQL query that lists all possible units that are compatible with the quantity *Time*, given that I have the following in my ontology?

```
Metre rdfs:subClassOf Unit
Second rdfs:subClassOf Unit
Hour rdfs:subClassOf Unit
Metre hasPhysicsDimension only LengthDimension
Second hasPhysicsDimension only TimeDimension
Hour hasPhysicsDimension only TimeDimension    
Time hasUnit only (hasPhysicsDimension only TimeDimension)
```

All entities in this ontology are classes. The expected result should be *Second*, *Hour*.

If the answer is "yes", what would that SPARQL query look like? [Query 13](https://www.w3.org/2009/Talks/0615-qbe/#q13) in the tutorial by Lee Feigenbaum, suggests combining `OPTIONAL` with a `!bound(...)` filter for universally quantified queries. But I haven't been able to make a working query based on this.

If it is not possible to construct such a query, can you comment on why, and would it help if we complement the ontology with existential restrictions?

```
Metre hasPhysicsDimension some LengthDimension
Second hasPhysicsDimension some TimeDimension
Hour hasPhysicsDimension some TimeDimension
```

Comment: This question might get more traction (i.e. more feedback) if it was posted instead in https://dba.stackexchange.com which is is devoted to database topics.

Comment: it's not really clear what in your ontology a class is and what are the instances. In your examples it looks like are both. That said, you have to query for the RDF triples that represent those complex OWL class expressions. `select * where { ?unit a ex:Unit;  rdfs:subClassOf [a owl:Restriction; owl:onProperty ex:hasPhysicsDimension; owl:allValuesFrom ex:TimeDimension ]}` - this returns all those units (untested because no RDF sample data provided

Comment: @UninformedUser, all entities in the ontology are classes. I have updated the question and make it clear. Also, thank you for the query. Based on it, I could construct a query that gives the expected result. However, it does so by inspecting  how the data is assessed and not by checking each unit if they satisfy all the universal restrictions.